# How to count the number of iterations in xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt

Inside an `xsl:for-each` loop I need the number of iterations to put in a `rowspan` attribute.

Is there in `xsl` something similar to the following?

```
for(int i = 0; i < collection.length(); i++)
```

I came to

```
<xsl:for-each select="foo">
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
      <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
          <xsl:value-of select=...collection.length()...
            etc
```

so the running counter `i` is no problem. But in the first iteration I need to get the total number of iterations, or the analogy to `collection.length()`, for the `rowspan=` number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `last()` function. Or define a variable as `count(foo)` before calling xsl:for-each.

Comment: I don't see how to convert `last()` to a number, but the variable works. I hesitated to experiment with variables because of remarks on the web that xsl variables cannot be changed, and my sample code actually is inside another outer `xsl:for-each` loop, but with your suggestion I got the variable to work.

Comment: @Roland `last()` returns a number. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-last But using a variable  might be more efficient (at least on some processors).

Comment: @michael.horz257k Thanks for pointing to the docs, but I would guess that using a variable set to `count(foo)`, and the for-each, would need two counting operations. But in my case performance is not an issue.

Comment: @Roland I guess it depends. I am not sure what your case use is (you show too little of your code).

Comment: @michael.horz257k lets say that I am more worried about how much time I need to get a little stylesheet to work than that my pc gets overheated :-)

Answer (score 1):

just further simplify you can use

```
<xsl:if test="position()=last()">
```

instead of taking count in the variable

Comment: Thanks, but I need the count on another line, as I noted in the edited question